# QGIS - Splitting a line into unequal segments based on height change

Tags: qgis, line, splitting, segment

I am writing here to look for other methods/approaches to the task that I am currently undertaking. The task is fairly simple at this stage: Create a set of layers showing the earthworks alongside the road.

I currently have the LIDAR data and the roads on the project, in addition to another 2 layers that are acting as guide rails, offset from the road.
I'd like to go along the Earthwork layers, cutting the line into discrete segments as the earthwork type changes. These segments will not be uniform and will be related to height changes.
My current method is to draw small polylines across the lines and to run the 'Line intersections' tool to get a set of points that I can take spatial data from.

This feels a little clunky and I was wondering if anyone else has had to do this or knows of a way that I could streamline this process, it would be brill.

p.s. in this case, an earthwork is anything >3m in height as measured from the road. I am thinking of how I can use the LIDAR data to possible automate the classification, perhaps by highlighting areas of height change.

p.p.s Screenshot added here - [image] - For instance, I would like to cut both the 'EW Right/Left' between the blue lines on the map, and also repeat this process for the rest of the road.

This would be the intended output, although I am looking to automate it over the lengths I have. [image]

Comment: Welcome to this GIS community. Secondly, I would suggest to either provide some screenshots and/or example data. This would make others understand better about what you want and what do you require?

Comment: Thanks datakeen, I have edited the original post with this information.

Comment: @GreenGoat you can post images (screenshot) directly to you post, no need to link to an external site. This makes it also easier to see everything together.

Comment: Thanks Babel! I didn't notice the option first time round!

Comment: What exactly is your goal? You want to split the line at a certain interval?

Comment: I want to create a line section that is colour coded to describe the type of earthwork either side of the carriageway. The type of earthwork is defined by the change in height (-ve or +ve). 
Imagine you were creating a set of lines to describe the type of shop along a high street, but you want each line to match up so that it appears to be a continuous line on the map. Ideally, you can then determine Spatial data (Start and end coordinates, length) of the individual line sections.

Comment: So lines perpendicular to the street? Sorry, still not clear...

Comment: So I have a linear feature (Road) that needs a database of earthworks (3 types: downward slope>3m, no slope, upwards slope >3m) present either side of the road (Picture in original post shows a road with a downward slope of both sides of the road). 
I want to make a layer that shows lines that represent the lengths of the earthwork, colour coded to the type and with x&y data for each end of the line. I have updated the original post as to what I see the output being.